# QML TextInput: inputMask to filter float values only

Tags: qml

I'm using QtQuick 1.0 and I'd like to have TextInput element with input to get only digits and ".". To obtain only digits I use the following code :

```
TextInput {
    id: textInput

    anchors.centerIn : inputArea
    font.family : "Helvetica"
    font.pixelSize: textSize
    color: "black"
    maximumLength: 5
    smooth: true
    inputMask: "99999"
    readOnly: isReadOnly
}
```

And I'm able to input only digits. How should I extend it to get "." also ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After several runs I came to the following solution :

```
TextInput {
    id: textInput

    anchors.centerIn : inputArea
    font.family : "Helvetica"
    font.pixelSize: textSize
    color: "black"
    maximumLength: 5
    smooth: true
    validator : RegExpValidator { regExp : /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ }
    readOnly: isReadOnly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [inputMethodHints](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#inputMethodHints-prop):

```
TextInput {
    id: textInput
    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can use a `RegExpValidator`, the proper way to handle such situations is probably to use `DoubleValidator` directly.

See the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-doublevalidator.html) for more details: it also provides some feature useful when working with floating point numbers.

```
TextInput {
    id: textInput

    anchors.centerIn : inputArea
    font.family : "Helvetica"
    font.pixelSize: textSize
    color: "black"
    smooth: true
    validator : DoubleValidator {
      decimals: 2
      top: 99999
      bottom: -99999
    }
    readOnly: isReadOnly
}
```